# Timestamp in python (year,month,day,hour,minute)

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, python-datetime

Currently im using

```
datetime.now()
```

The result im getting is for example

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 4, 10, 14, 20, 768814)
```

My goal is to get

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 4, 10, 14, 20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace):

```
>>> datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 4, 9, 24, 32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. If you don't want the microseconds, use below:

```
datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)

Output ---> datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 4, 14, 53, 44)
```